# Transfer GeoJSON data to a MySQL database

Tags: geojson, import, database, mysql

I want to transfer my GeoJSON data to a MySQL database. I know that MySQL somehow supports GeoJSON but I do not really understand how that works.

That was my try:

```
SET @point_o_from_geoJSON := ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.721926,49.856657]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.428072,50.052724],[8.428072,50.190024],[8.807062,50.190024],[8.807062,50.052724],[8.428072,50.052724]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[9.177812,50.151338]}}]}' ); # geometry from geoJSON
select ST_AsText(@point_o_from_geoJSON) AS `point_o_from_geoJSON`;
```

But then my table looks like:

[image: table with all information in one column]

I would like that one column shows the type (Point/Polygon/...), one the features if there are some (color,...) and one column for the coordinates.

Comment: have you thought of using `ogr2ogr`?

Comment: @IanTurton No, I haven't heard of `ogr2ogr` before. I just looked it up, but how could I use it to transfer my geojson data to my mysql database? Could you explain it a bit closer, please?